# Javascript modal pass dynamic variable in popup depending on dynamic id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, popup, bootstrap-modal

```
    <a id="wishlisticon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#wishlist-modal" data-productid="1"></a>
    <a id="wishlisticon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#wishlist-modal" data-productid="2"></a>
    <a id="wishlisticon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#wishlist-modal" data-productid="3"></a>
    <a id="wishlisticon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#wishlist-modal" data-productid="4"></a>

<script>
    $('#wishlist-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
       var $el = $("#wishlisticon");
       var $username = $el.data('productid');
       alert($username);
    });
</script>
```

There are several buttons on a page pointing to the same modal, however different data needs to be passed for each modal.
The data to be passed is saved in `data-productid.`
When the popup modal opens, I want to use data-productid variable.

The function is working but each time the alert is giving the same productid value (i.e = 1)
The function is not able to understand that it should pickup the corresponding data-productid

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-related-target), you can use `event.relatedTarget` to vary the contents of the modal depending on which button was clicked.

```
$('#wishlist-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
   var $el = $(event.relatedTarget);
   var $username = $el.data('productid');
   alert($username);
});
```

DEMO:

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
  alert(recipient)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="1">Open modal for 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="2">Open modal for 2t</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="3">Open modal for 3</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have applied this and I get the value as undefined.

Comment: Can you try to change `shown.bs.modal` to `show.bs.modal` once and test again. Also have you passed `event` inside `function(event) {` ?

Comment: The result is the same. Can I share the website URL here?

Comment: Check the demo I have added once. Is it working for you?

Comment: I have done exactly the same, used data-target as well.
The alert comes before the modal opens.
The alert value is undefined

Comment: Also, try to remove `id="wishlisticon"` from all the links, as ids are supposed to be unique in dom. Or, you can rename them to `wishlisticon1`, `wishlisticon2` and so on and then try again.

Comment: I have been trying them without the ID.

Comment: Also, you didn't answer. Is this demo working for you?

Comment: This means that there is some issue with your code at your end. Might be jquery or bootstrap version or something. Can't help much with that from here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210979/discussion-between-arpan-jain-and-pala).

Comment: I dont think this is a jquery or bootstrap error as the alert gives the value with inital code as posted in the question. It doesnt work when I try to show it different for each button modal.